# How assing Register Js Object of Cefsharp with MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, dependency-properties, cefsharp

I need a help.
Im trying to use cefsharp with MVVM (wpf). Now I have a problem with pass js register object to VM. 
For this I create own UserControl in assembly **'X.Browser'** with XAML code

```
<UserControl x:Class="XXX.Browser.WebBrowser"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
         mc:Ignorable="d"            
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="browser" Margin="0"/>
```

and code behind:

```
public partial class WebBrowser : UserControl
{
    private RequestHandler _requestHandler;

    public WebBrowser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // This is the binding, which binds the property of the VM
        // to your dep. property.
        // My convention is give my property wrapper in the view the same
        // name as the property in the VM has.
        var binding = new Binding(nameof(JsCallbackObject)) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        this.SetBinding(JsCallbackObjectProperty, binding); 
        RegisterJsObject();

        InitBrowser();
    }

    // add browser handler
    private void InitBrowser()
    {
        this.browser.LifeSpanHandler = new LifeSpanHandler();
        this.browser.MenuHandler = new ContextMenuHandler();
        _requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
        this.browser.RequestHandler = _requestHandler; 
    }

    // reg js obj
    private void RegisterJsObject()
    {
        var jsCallbackObject = new JsCallbackObject(this.browser);
        this.browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject(jsCallbackObject.Name, jsCallbackObject);
        JsCallbackObject = jsCallbackObject;
    }

    #region DP JsCallbackObject
    public JsCallbackObject JsCallbackObject
    {
        get { return (JsCallbackObject)GetValue(JsCallbackObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(JsCallbackObjectProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty JsCallbackObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(JsCallbackObject),
            typeof(JsCallbackObject),
            typeof(WebBrowser),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnFolderChanged)
        );

    private static void OnFolderChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // just wanted to test if we get here, which we do everytime
        // MessageBox.Show("WeChanged");
        // var x = d;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

When i try use this UserControl in view in another assembly
**NewMainView**

```
 <br:WebBrowser x:Name="brou" Grid.Row="2" 
                   cal:Bind.Model="Y.ViewModels.NewMainViewModel"
                   JsCallbackObject="{Binding Path=JsCallbackObject , Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>
```

**NewMainViewModel:**

```
    class NewMainViewModel : Screen
{
private JsCallbackObject _jsCallbackObject;
    JsCallbackObject JsCallbackObject
    {
        get { return _jsCallbackObject; }
        set { Set(ref _jsCallbackObject, value); }
    }
    protected async override void OnViewAttached(object view, object context)
    {
        base.OnViewAttached(view, context);

        var ctx = context; 
         var jco = JsCallbackObject ;
    }
```

jco = is null. Where is my fault?